# How to define a singe weak reference in elisp?

Tags: hash-tables, garbage-collect

Hash tables in elisp supports weak references, however weak references may be useful without the need to use a hash.

How can a weak reference to an object be defined without having to use a hash-table containing one item?

Comment: Submit a patch for such a data structure, wait some time, use it in the next Emacs release. Alternatively you can speed up the process with an Emacs module or fake it with hash tables: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2012/12/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General-purpose weak references would indeed be a useful general-purpose feature for elisp.

It's worth mentioning that in lieu of that functionality, there's a mini convenience library for exactly the strategy you mention (using a hash table with weak values and a single constant as a key) to obtain an effective weak reference: [elisp-weak-ref](https://github.com/skeeto/elisp-weak-ref).